# How to set permission in custom module?

Tags: users

I have a custom module and i want the "form-example" only open for admin user and form-submissions open for anyone.

> **form-example.module**

```
<?php
function form_example_permission() {
  return array(
    'submit form_example' => array(
      'title' => t('Submit form_example'),
      'description' => t('Submit the form_example form'),
    ),
    'access form_example submissions' => array(
      'title' => t('Access form_example submissions'),
      'description' => t('Access the form_example submissions'),
    ),
  );
}
function form_example_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['form-example'] = array( //this creates a URL that will call this form at "examples/form-example"
    'title' => 'Example Form', //page title
    'description' => 'A form to mess around with.',
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    'access arguments' => array('submit form_example'),
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form', //this is the function that will be called when the page is accessed.  for a form, use drupal_get_form
    'page arguments' => array('form_example_form'),

      );

 $items['form-submissions'] = array(
    'title' => t('List'),
    'page callback' => 'form_example_submissions',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'access arguments' => array('access form_example submissions'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;
}

function form_example_form($form, &$form_state) {

$form['empcode'] = array(
  '#weight' => '0',
  '#required' => '1',
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('Employee Code'),
);
$form['empname'] = array(
  '#weight' => '1',
  '#required' => '1',
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('Employee Name'),
);
$form['file'] = array(
  '#weight' => '2',
  '#type' => 'file',
  '#size' => '30',
  '#title' => t('Employee Photo'),
);
 $form['submit'] = array(
     '#weight' => '3',
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Submit'),
  );

return $form;

}

function form_example_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  /*if (!($form_state['values']['price'] > 0)){
    form_set_error('price', t('Price must be a positive number.'));
  }*/
 // print('<pre>'.print_r($form_state['values'],1).'</pre>');
  //die();
 $file = file_save_upload('file', array(
    'file_validate_is_image' => array(),
    'file_validate_extensions' => array('png gif jpg jpeg'),
  ));
  if ($file) {
    if ($file = file_move($file, 'public://')) {
      $form_state['values']['file'] = $file;
    }
    else {
      form_set_error('file', t('Failed to write the uploaded file the site\'s file folder.'));
    }
  }
  else {
    form_set_error('file', t('No file was uploaded.'));
  }
}

function form_example_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
   $file=$form_state['values']['file'];
  unset($form_state['values']['file']);
  $file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
  file_save($file);
  drupal_set_message(t('The form has been submitted and the image has been saved, filename: @filename.', array('@filename' => $file->filename)));


 $fe_id = db_insert('form_example')
        ->fields(array(

          'empcode' => $form_state['values']['empcode'],
          'empname' => $form_state['values']['empname'],
          'empphoto' => $file->filename,
        ))
        ->execute();
        drupal_set_message(t('Successfully added'));

}
function form_example_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'form_example_function' => array(
      'variables' => array('rows' => NULL),
    ),
    'form_example_template' => array(
      'variables' => array('rows' => NULL),
      'template' => 'form_example_template',
    ),


  );
}

/* view the form submissions*/
function form_example_submissions()
{
  $results =  db_query("Select * from {form_example}");
   $rows = array();
  foreach($results as $result)
  {
    $rows[] = array(
        $result->fe_id,
        $result->empcode,
        $result->empname,
        $result->empphoto,
      );

  }
  return theme('form_example_function',array('rows' => $rows));
}
/*function theme_form_example_function($variables)
{
  print_r($variables);
//$output ="<h2>".print_r$variables."</pre></h2>";
/*  foreach ($variables as $result)
  {

    $output = "<h2><pre>".print_r($result)."</pre></h2>";
  }
return $output;
 $output = '';

    foreach($variables['rows'] as $row) {
        foreach($row as $values) {

          print_r($values);
         $output .= "Empcode: " . $values . "</br> ";
         // $output .= "EmpName: " . $values[1] . " </br>";
        //$output .= "Emphot: " . $values[2] . "\n";
        }
    }
    return $output;

}*/
function theme_form_example_function($variables)
{
    $output = '';

    foreach($variables['rows'] as $row) {
      //  echo $path;
      // $output .= "Empcode: " . (isset($row[1]) ? $row[1] : "--") . " ";
      //  $output .= "EmpName: " . (isset($row[2]) ? $row[2] : "--") . " ";
      //  $output .= "Emphot: " . (isset($row[3]) ? $row[3] : "--") . "<br>";   

$img_url = 'public://'.(isset($row[3]) ? $row[3] : "--");  // the orig image uri
$style = 'medium';  // or any other custom image style you've created via /admin/config/media/image-styles



     $output .= '<div class="views-row"><div class="do_featured">
  <div style="position: relative;" class="do_image"> 
            <div class="field field-name-field-thumb-image field-type-image field-label-hidden"><div class="field-items"><div class="field-item "><img  src="'.image_style_url($style, $img_url).'" ></div></div></div></div>
  <div class="do_title">
    <span>    <div class="field"><div class="field-items">Employee Name:</div><div class="field-items">'.(isset($row[2]) ? $row[2] : "--") .'</div></div>
 <div class="field"><div class="field-items">Employee Code:</div><div class="field-items">'.(isset($row[1]) ? $row[1] : "--") .'</div></div> 


      </span> 
   </div></div></div>';



    }

    return $output;
}


?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your admin role permissions for 'submit form_example', and then give both authenticated and anonymous roles permission for access 'form_example submissions'.

Comment: buddy am new to drupal can you please tell me where can i give these permissions

Comment: If you're using Drupal 7, you need to go to admin/people/permissions

Comment: For custom form i think need to implement permission hook to get this.